# AssertionError trying to VisualiceNetworks

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm trying to create a network connection graph with import networkx as nx and from pyvis.network import Network. The code is as follows

```
rules = pd.read_csv("EDMV.conexiones_neg.20220613.apriori.base2.txt", sep = "|")
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(rules, source = "desc.x", target = "desc.y", edge_attr = "lift")
net = Network(notebook = True, width=1000, height=600)
net.from_nx(G)
```

When I run the finale line I get an AssertionError.

Any ideas what is causing error?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to make sure that your nodes label type are either integer or string (in your case 'desc.x' and 'desc.y' columns).

try the following:

```
rules = pd.read_csv("EDMV.conexiones_neg.20220613.apriori.base2.txt", sep = "|")
rules["desc.x"] = rules["desc.x"].astype(str)
rules["desc.y"] = rules["desc.y"].astype(str)
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(rules, source = "desc.x", target = "desc.y", edge_attr = "lift")
net = Network(notebook = True, width=1000, height=600)
net.from_nx(G)
```